# Ffmpeg-Build: Error during build

Tags: android, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

I am building ffmpeg and stuck in an unusual spot. Inside libavutil we have float_dsp.h and float_dsp.c files. Inside these file there is a declaration of a methond which is:

```
void (*butterflies_float)(float *av_restrict v1, float *av_restrict v2, int len);
float (*scalarproduct_float)(const float *v1, const float *v2, int len);
```

when building and compiling this file i get this error and have no idea what to do. I think problem is somewhere else but again have no idea at all. Error is

```
jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/../libavutil/float_dsp.h:150: error: expected ';', ',' or ')'  before 'v1'
jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/../libavutil/float_dsp.h:161: error: expected ';' before 'float'
```

Anybody who wants to help please take a step forward because i have not really got any support on ffmpeg during couple of weeks now.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by:

- not set GCC to C99 mode where `restrict` keyword is supported
- `restrict` was redefined by some #define
- `restrict` is not supported for particular architecture but this is unlikely
- GCC is set to C++ mode where `restrict` keyword is not supported GCC according http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html.

There are other supported forms by GCC like `__restrict` and `__restrict__`.
ffmpeg configure script sets macro `av_restrict` to just `restrict` which can be checked in produced config.h file.

Fix could be to change configure detection code and remove invalid case `restrict`:

```
--- ./configure.orig    2014-01-15 18:53:59.000000000 +0100
+++ ./configure 2014-03-13 17:50:45.754442028 +0100
@@ -3896,7 +3896,7 @@
 EOF

 _restrict=
-for restrict_keyword in restrict __restrict__ __restrict; do
+for restrict_keyword in __restrict__ __restrict; do
     check_cc <<EOF && _restrict=$restrict_keyword && break
 void foo(char * $restrict_keyword p);
 EOF
```